# Generating Proper Links from Names

Tags: php, regex

I am attempting to generate proper links from proper names...

For example: **T & J Automotive** is currently generated as **/t-j-automotive**

But, because I need to do a look up based on the name, I am unable to do said lookup when attempting to convert back to the name.

So...   I've take care of ' by converting them to _, which works great for names like Mike's Shop (converts to mike_s-shop), but now I am faced with the &

Here is my current function:

```
// Fix the name for a SEO friendly URL
function FixNameForLink($str){
    // Swap out Non "Letters" with a -
    $text = preg_replace('/[^\\pL\d\']+/u', '-', $str);
    // Trim out extra -'s
    $text = trim($text, '-');
    // Convert letters that we have left to the closest ASCII representation
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    // Make text lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);
    // ' has been valid until now... swap it for an _
    $text = str_replace('\'', '_', $text);
    // & has been valid until now... swap it for an .
    $text = str_replace('&', '.', $text);
    // Strip out anything we haven't been able to convert
    $text = preg_replace('/[^-_\w]+/', '', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Note, the & replacement is not happenning.   How can I make sure that any string passed to this function will have ' replace with _, and & replaced with .?

Comment: Your code contains operations that in general are not reversible, therefore it is impossible to get the original input starting from the fixed name. You have taken the wrong path on this. If you need the original input then preserve it.

Comment: Please re-read what I need...  it's in the question.  I understand your concerns, but my needs differ from them.

Comment: You write "I am unable to do said lookup when attempting to convert back to the name". I 'm saying that you *cannot* convert back to the name in the general case because you are doing things like indiscriminate replacement of characters with dashes. When your needs conflict with reality, reality always wins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
// Fix the name for a SEO friendly URL
function FixNameForLink($str){
    // Swap out Non "Letters" with a -
    $text = preg_replace('/[^\\pL\d\'&]+/u', '-', $str); // needed to allow the &
    // Trim out extra -'s
    $text = trim($text, '-');
    // Convert letters that we have left to the closest ASCII representation
    $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
    // Make text lowercase
    $text = strtolower($text);
    // ' has been valid until now... swap it for an _
    $text = str_replace('\'', '_', $text);
    // & has been valid until now... swap it for an .
    $text = str_replace('&', '.', $text);
    // Strip out anything we haven't been able to convert
    $text = preg_replace('/[^-_\.\w]+/', '', $text); // needed to make sure the replace . stays put 
    return $text;
}
```